# where to store html strings on client for later DOM insertion?

Tags: javascript, html

In a single-page-application, there are certain views (i.e. chunks of html code) that are not shown at the start, but may be shown later. I can append these views to the DOM when needed, but I don't want to have to dynamically load them from the server. Instead I want to load them from the server when the rest of the page loads. Where is the best place to put such multi-line html chunks, so that they can easily be accessed from javascript and appended to the DOM? Does there exist special html tags for this kind of thing?

Comment: HTML5 session storage?

Comment: Can't you just hide them until you need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store theses html parts in `div` width `display:none` (one `div` by html part), to show them when needed, where needed (by manipulating DOM structure).